# laravel taking too long time to generate pdf with more than 2000 pages at a time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-snappy

I'm working on a Laravel project, which requires printing 2000+ pages at a time. I've used the package Laravel snappy for generating the PDF. But the problem is, it takes a lot of time to load and eventually gives me `504 error`. How can I overcome this problem?

Is there any better and faster solution to carry out such operation?
Is there any alternative way to print directly from the live server database?
I'm providing a link below, which resembles a similar situation:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-wkhtmltopdf-taking-long-time-to-generate-pdf-with-more-than-30-pages

Comment: you could make this into a job and have it run in the background then have a way to inform the user that it is ready perhaps

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there’s an easy solution for your problem.

2000+ pages in PDF means a huge amount of data for any library/language, probably you simply don’t have to build it on a live transaction.

If applicable, you should register a cron job and build the pdf in background. Or you can register a job to be picked up by a worker and expose an endpoint the user can poll to check if the building process has finished.